# What happens to previous Nirguna Parabrahmans from previous cosmic cycles?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, gods

Trying to find this answer for many years and unable to receive answer

If Parabrahman can take different forms after each Mahapralaya, then what happens to the previous Nirguna Parabrahmans from previous cosmic cycles?
If Parabrahman took the Nirguna form of Mahavishnu for this cosmic cycle after the previous previous Mahapralaya, what happens to the Nirguna Parabrahman who ruled the previous cosmic cycle? Are they just merged back into Parabrahman and ceases to exist?

Comment: Try to learn basics of Vedanta first, and then you will understand those things. There is only one Brahman or Parabrahman, and there cannot be more than one. There is no such thing like Nirguna Parabrahmans. Learning Vedanta is very important, it enables one to properly understand anything which Hindu scriptures teach.